# ajax and php updating mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database

i am having problem updating the database.

Basically what i am trying to do is everytime a download link is clicked the download count in the database goes up.

Can someone point me in the right direction as i have been trying to get this right for hours :(

Here is the html.

```
<div class="button_border_dark"> <a id="linkcounter" href="http://www.derby-web-design-agency.co.uk/freeby-download/<?php echo $freebies_download ; ?>" target="_blank" title="Download">Click To Download File</a></div>
```

Here is the jquery

```
<script>
$('#linkcounter').bind('click',function(){
    $.post("downloadcount.php",{ linkid: <?php echo $id ; ?>});
});
</script>
```

Here is the downloadcount.php which i am trying to post data too, so it updates the content.

```
<?php
require_once("applications/constants/connection.php");
require_once("applications/controllers/basic.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST["linkid"])){

$linkid = sanitise($_POST["linkid"]);

$updatedownload = mysql_query("UPDATE freebies SET download_count=`download_count` +1 WHERE id ='".$linkid."'") OR die(mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: do you get any errors? What does the console say about the request?

Comment: @Topener the only error i get is

event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

But i do not think that is related

Comment: Okay you need to start dumping vars to determine at what point your program breaks. var_dump( $_POST ) in your downloadcount.php. My guess is your query is breaking. Also, you are quoting your id value in the query. I'll bet you should be treating that as an integer. Dump, and let me know what it says... P.S. What does the response say  in your browser dev tools? Is it spitting back anything at all?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte No errors are coming back. The single quotes within the mysql_query are backticks which is good practice for sql queries when calling a column within the sql query, just incase i did try it without the backticks and still no joy.

I think that its not even acknowledging that the link has been clicked. Because its not spitting any errors what so ever within the log.

Comment: var_dump($_POST["linkid"]). What does it say?

Comment: How about var_dump( $linkid ). Does it spit anything out?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what is the problem!

Is not incrementing? is incrementing too much? is one process blocking the other? the problem is that people can cheat and make so a file has ben downloaded a million times?

Anyway, I think you code can be simpler.

```
$('#linkcounter').click(function(){
    $("#invisibleiframe").attr("src",$(this).attr("src");
    $.post("downloadcount.php",{ linkid: <?php echo $id ; ?>});
    return false;
});
```

this need to create a invisible iframe, that will be the one downloaded the file. after starting this download, the ajax request is made.  a single event do the two things. made this way the stuff still works if js is disabled.

Comment: You still don't say what is the problem, so we poke things around randomly with hope to hit the problem by pure luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think should be

```
$updatedownload = mysql_query("UPDATE freebies SET download_count= download_count +1 WHERE id ='".$linkid."'") OR die(mysql_error());
```

Note the single quote:

```
SET download_count = download_count +1
```

Comment: Kait Wee - Is that not the same?

Answer (score 0):

Well first off I would not mix the jQuery and PHP personally, this may be the source of your problem, I would try something like this

```
<div class="button_border_dark" theLinkId="<?php echo $id ; ?>">
    <a id="linkcounter" href="http://yourURL/" target="_blank" title="Download">
      Click To Download File
    </a>
</div>
```

With the jQuery like this

```
<script>
$('#linkcounter').bind('click',function(){
    var theLinkId = $(this).parent().attr('theLinkId');
    $.post("downloadcount.php",{ linkid : theLinkId});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, i just tried your code and still no joy :(

Comment: I would get FireBug if you don't already have it and change the jQuery to something like.. `$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "downloadcount.php", data: "linkid=theLinkId"}).done(function( msg ) { console.log(msg); }});`  If you luck it sill output some error that is being hidden for some reason.

Comment: Also have you tried removing `if(isset($_REQUEST["linkid"]))` or setting the sql to something not dependent on the POST data like `"UPDATE freebies SET download_count=10 WHERE id=5"` .. I just noticed as I was copy/pasting this that you had `id ='".$linkid."'` if id is an int then I think it should be `id='.$linkid.'`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your event is not actually being bound to the anchor, because you are running `.bind()` before the anchor exists. Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#linkcounter').bind('click',function(){
        $.post("downloadcount.php",{ linkid: <?php echo $id ; ?>});
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

how many anchors you have with id = 'linkcounter' ?

If you have more than one, i recommend you to change 'id' for 'class'

Greatings.

EDIT:

Try something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.cl" onclick="goToLink(this, 1);">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function goToLink(o, id) {
    $.post("downloadcounter.php",
           {linkid : id},
           function () {
               window.open($(this).attr("href"));
           }
    );

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: There will only ever be 1 on a page

Comment: <a href="http://www.google.cl" onclick="goToLink(this, 1);">Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google2.cl" onclick="goToLink(this, 2);">Link</a>